# Changing elements in a matrix in Clojure

Tags: for-loop, vector, clojure

I'm very new to Clojure and functional programming in general, and I'm wondering how to do the following:

I have a vector of vectors called `s` that looks something like this:

```
user=> (println s)
[[1 1 1 3] [2 2 2 3] [3 2 1 1] [4 3 3 4]]
```

What I want to do is 'loop' through each inner-vector of `s` and change the second element to a different string, *based on the number being replaced*. The end result might be something like this:

```
; Hopeful Result:
user=> (println new-s)
[[1 "Joe" 1 3] [2 "Fred" 2 3] [3 "Fred" 1 1] [4 "Martha" 3 4]]
```

This idea I have so far is to use `for` to loop through each vector, and from there pass the individual vector to another function that uses `assoc`:

```
(for [line s] (assemble [line]))

(defn assemble [line]
  (let [x (- (read-string (line 1)) 1)])     ; ==> 0 (To match vector of string names)
  (assoc line 1 new-name[x]))
```

But I'm having trouble passing a single vector to my func `assemble`. It seems to be passing not the vector data but the reference to it. Is there a better way to accomplish this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

something like this would do the trick:

```
(def data [[1 1 1 3] [2 2 2 3] [3 2 1 1] [4 3 3 4]])

(def replacements {1 "joe" 2 "fred" 3 "martha"})

user> (mapv (fn [row] (update row 1 replacements)) data)
;;=> [[1 "joe" 1 3] [2 "fred" 2 3] [3 "fred" 1 1] [4 "martha" 3 4]]
```

in your case, you just pass a wrong argument to your `assemble` function: you wrap it in a vector, which you don't need.

```
user> (def names ["joe" "fred" "martha"])
#'user/names

user> (defn assemble [line]
        (assoc line 1 (names (dec (line 1)))))
#'user/assemble

user> (for [line data] (assemble line))
;;=> ([1 "joe" 1 3] [2 "fred" 2 3] [3 "fred" 1 1] [4 "martha" 3 4])
```

and then you can rewrite the `assemble` to use `update`:

```
user> (defn assemble [line]
        (update line 1 (comp names dec)))
#'user/assemble

user> (for [line data] (assemble line))
;;=> ([1 "joe" 1 3] [2 "fred" 2 3] [3 "fred" 1 1] [4 "martha" 3 4])

user> (mapv assemble data)
;;=> [[1 "joe" 1 3] [2 "fred" 2 3] [3 "fred" 1 1] [4 "martha" 3 4]]
```

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is at the point where you pass the sub vector to your `assemble` function:

```
(for [line s] (assemble [line]))
```

You wrap the sub vector `line` inside another vector so you end up passing `[[1 2 3]]` instead of `[1 2 3]`.

Just write

```
(for [line s] (assemble line))
```

and everything should be okay.

*Edit:*

You should read more on the syntax of Clojure and Lisps in general. Your code will not work in so many ways.
For example:

- `let` creates a local binding. The "variables" you declare inside its vector are only available inside the `let` statement. So accessing `x` in your `assoc` statement won't work. What you want to do is to put the `assoc` call directly in front of the closing bracket of `let` like: `(let [x 1] (assoc line 1 x))`
- I do not know what you want to achieve by writing `new-name[x]`, maybe accessing a char inside a string? This won't work. Such syntactic shenanigans do not exist in Lisps. You would use a function for this. If I guessed correctly, look at the `clojure.string` namespace.
- Writing `(line 1)` will give you a nice exception along the lines of "don't know how to use a string as a function". The identifier that comes directly after an opening parenthesis can only be the name of a function, a macro or a symbol. A string is something you can't invoke, even in Clojure.

I suggest strongly that you should read something like http://www.braveclojure.com/, especially the first few chapters.

Answer (score -2):

Here are 4 ways of doing it.  Methods 1 & 2 use the `tupelo.array` functions.

```
(ns tst.demo.core
  (:use demo.core tupelo.core tupelo.test)
  (:require [tupelo.array :as tar] ))

(def data
  [[1 1 1 3]
   [2 2 2 3]
   [3 2 1 1]
   [4 3 3 4]])

(dotest
  (let [arr          (tar/rows->array data)
        result-1     (-> arr
                       (tar/elem-set 0 1 "Joe") ; can be in any order here
                       (tar/elem-set 3 1 "Martha")
                       (tar/elem-set 2 1 "Fred")
                       (tar/elem-set 1 1 "Fred"))

        row-name-map {0 "Joe"
                      2 "Fred"
                      3 "Martha"
                      1 "Fred"}
        result-2     (reduce
                       (fn [cum-arr [row-idx name]]
                         (tar/elem-set cum-arr row-idx 1 name))
                       arr
                       row-name-map)
```

Method 2b uses native clojure `assoc-in`, treating the nested vectors as associative data structures like maps.

```
        result-2b    (reduce
                       (fn [cum-arr [row-idx name]]
                         (assoc-in cum-arr [row-idx 1] name))
                       arr
                       row-name-map)
```

Method 3 uses mutable Java-native arrays.

```
        jarr-3       (to-array-2d arr) ; native java, mutable array
        >>           (doseq [[row-idx name] row-name-map] ; imperative code
                       (aset jarr-3 row-idx 1 name))
        result-3     (mapv vec jarr-3) ] ; convert back to nested clojure vecs
```

All 4 techniques produce identical results:

```
    (is= result-1 result-2 result-2b result-3
      [[1 "Joe" 1 3]
       [2 "Fred" 2 3]
       [3 "Fred" 1 1]
       [4 "Martha" 3 4]])))
```

More [documentation can be found here](https://github.com/cloojure/tupelo).

Comment: OP's got multiple typing errors and stumbles over the first one. To suggest something like using a completely different library, for something that doesn't even use `clojure.core` that extensively, brought us to the point of "why use + in js if you could use jQuery instead?"